Webot Solid falling down upon running
I am creating a simple project with world containing a Solid square. After adding physics to it (mass 0.1, density -1), the Solid falls from the world when I run it. This is my first time working with webots. Can someone please provide some pointers or suggestion on how to fix it.
Thanks
